# Is int() a standalone function or it is actually an _init_ constructor method of the int class under covers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, sys

(a) I am trying to figure out whether `int(), float(), tuple()` and similar functions are standalone functons or they work like constructors for user classes (i.e. invoking class `__init__()` method under covers.)

(b) I wanted to find available  signatures of these methods, like `int(str)`, `int(str, base)`.

(c) I tried peeking into the source code on github, but it seems to be implemented on the c-layer, not on Python-layer. There is even no header-like stub Python code for this.

Comment: Type `help(int)` and you'll see that it's the name of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of those are classes, they are class objects. Their `type` is `type` (which itself, is a class, a metaclass):

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

Same as a custom class:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'type'>
```

And seemingly paradoxically:

```
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
```

NOTE: **None** of these objects are the `__init__`. That is a special method *that gets called* by the constructor to run custom initialization. IOW:

```
>>> Foo.__init__ is Foo
False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `help(int)` you'll see that it's the name of a class:

```
Help on class int in module builtins:

class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
```

However, if you scan further down, you won't see an `__init__` method. Instances are initialized by internal C code in the `__new__` method of the class.

Comment: While its correct that the `int` class doesn't have an `__init__` method, that's mostly because it's immutable, and you can't initialize an `int` object after it's been constructed. Instead the setup work happens in `__new__` (which is indeed implemented in C, but it does have a Python interface).

Comment: @Blckknght I believe all of these inherit `object.__init__` which doesn't do anything, but it's there...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assume that's just so that `super().__init__()` always finds something

Comment: **Barmar**, **Juanpa Arrivillaga**, **Blckknight**, thank you very much for the insights.